# Can anyone decipher the name of this Royal Navy ship in Beruit in 1861?

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, united-kingdom, navy, census-records

Can anyone work out what the name of this ship is for me please it is from the 1861 census reference RG9/4441/232/30[image]

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I read "H M Ship 'Queen.'"

See the Wikipedia article, "[HMS Queen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Queen)," for "Seven ships of the Royal Navy have been named HMS Queen."

In particular, note the number of guns in, "HMS Queen was a 110-gun first rate launched in 1839. In 1859 the ship was fitted with a screw propeller and reduced to 86 guns. She was broken up in 1871."

More about this specific HMS Queen available at Wikipedia, "[HMS Queen (1839)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Queen_%281839%29)," which also references the 1859 re-fitting. Reports that, "...being able to cruise at 10.5 knots she was commissioned into the Mediterranean Fleet until 1864."

The Wikipedia article cites

1. "Lyon & Winfield, *[The Sail & Steam Navy List 1815-1889](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sail-Steam-Navy-List-1815-1889/dp/1861760329)*."
2. "'[Timmy the tortoise dies aged 160](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/england/devon/3607053.stm)' BBC News 7 April 2004."
3. "Rankin, Stuart (July 2004). *Shipyards, Granaries and Wharves, Maritime Rotherhithe, History Walk B. London: Southwark Council*. ISBN 0-905849-37-X." [This reference can be downloaded as a pdf from associated link in the the Wikipedia article.]

**Pretty picture**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for that the first letter looked nothing like a Q to me.

Comment: @Colin I agree. A less flowery "Q" or at least better formed letters "e" (they reach a bit) would have made the word more easily identifiable.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with GeneJ. HM Ship Queen.

Further research on this [site](http://www.pdavis.nl/ShowShip.php?id=36) shows that on 17 November 1859 Captain Charles Farrell Hillyar was in command of the ship in the Mediterranean.

Comment: Nice work, @AvieRose.